Recursive definition depending on multiple previous values (Analysis I Tao)
I'm reading Analysis I from Tao, and he defines recursive definitions as:
Proposition 2.1.16 (Recursive definitions). Suppose for each natural number $n$, we have some function $f_{n} : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ from the natural numbers to the natural numbers. Let $c$ be a natural number. Then we can assign a unique natural number $a_{n}$ to each natural number $n$, such that $a_{0} = c$ and $a_{n{++}} = f_{n} (a_{n})$ for each natural number $n$.
Then we have proposition 8.1.5 which says:
Proposition 8.1.5 Let $X$ be an infinite subset of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. Then there exists a unique bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$ which is increasing, in the sense that $f(n + 1) \gt f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In particular, $X$ has equal cardinality with $\mathbb{N}$ and hence countable.
In the proof, Tao defines a sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots$ with $a_0$ being the minimum element of $X$ (well-ordering principle), and $a_n = \min \{x\in X: x \neq a_m \mbox{ for all } m \lt n \}$. Then says that to define $a_n$ one only needs to know the values of $a_m$ for all $m \lt n$, so the definition is recursive.
My question is, in Tao definition of recursive definition, the value of $a_n$ only depends on $a_{n-1}$. Have I a wrong understanding of the recursive definition of Tao? Or do we need an extension of his definition, where the new values depend on all the previous values?

You can prove a custom version of Proposition 2.1.16 where now $a_{n++} = f_n(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$. The proof works the same.

Check if Tao doesn't mention the more general version somewhere in the text. In particular, check if there isn't an exercise that discusses and leads to a proof of it. If not, then this is something that should be reported to Tao, that he references a stronger version of recursive (a.k.a, inductive) definition than he proves.
